# Create a program in C++ to calculate all possible equations

Tags: c++, algorithm, brute-force

I have an assignment to create a C++ program to find all the possible mathematic equation with operators. Below shows the question:

> Given a set of numbers, for example {5, 3, 7, 3, and 11}. Find all the possible mathematic equation with operators such as +, - ,*, / in such a way that the equation will produce the given answer. For example, 5+7-3/3=11.

I need an idea how to start with the code. Is it like brute force algorithm ? I have no idea how to interchange the operators to create the possible equation. I'm not asking for full solution, just an idea how to start the coding.

Comment: brute-force is an option, but you can also save the results to be faster

Comment: Despite of down-votes, it looks like an interesting question regarding both programming and maths. You could try to make an algorithm to solve this  by brute force, indeed, but you got plenty of code to write for al the possible solutions

Comment: I don't see a way around the brute force approach. This is quite the interesting question... Do the sets of numbers vary in size? The example shows an array of 5 numbers, but could there be more or fewer numbers than that?

Comment: also you have to give a few more information about the problem... for example how big must be the array? or should it be implemented dynamicly?

Comment: @JamesAdkison no, there aren't infinite solutions, just a few, but a great number of possibilities to test

Comment: @meJustAndrew I already removed my comment because I decided to assume that each number in the set could only be used once (and each must be used once). However, since I didn't see that constraint explicitly stated there would be an infinite number of solutions (but that doesn't make any sense).

Comment: The array numbers is varies bro.  The main objective of this assignment is   highest possible of equation. Groups  that managed to have many equation with correct solution win the game.

Comment: @7Nate9 backtracking?

Comment: Can you use brackets, such as in (5-3)*7 = 11+3  ?

Comment: Yez bro can use bracket and even modulas operator too. but we cannot touch the solution bro. Cannot play with 11.

Comment: If no braces are used the total numbers of possibilities is given by the computation 4^4 which is 1048.

Comment: Using brackets and modulus... I am sorry for you!

Comment: Hahahaha bracket is a optional only to create more equation. By the way, the array of number size varies up to 15 numbers

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz bro can you elaborate about backtracking.

Comment: A very similar question is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133101/find-expressions-equal-to-a-given-number-using-15-integers-with-4-operators (originally posted on SO as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036297/optimization-using-15-integers-with-4-operators-to-compute-all-possible-soluti).

Answer (score 3):

You could think about it like this. +,-,*,/ can be treated as 1,2,3,4 respectively. Now, if you were to try all the different combinations for whatever size array of numbers you get, you could look at it like this. 
example. 4 numbers.

```
1,1,1,1  1,1,1,2  1,1,1,3  1,1,1,4

1,1,2,1  1,1,2,2  1,1,2,3  1,1,2,4
```

and so on and so forth. Hope this might help!

Comment: but be careful with the * and / they are binding more than + and -

Comment: This is pretty relevant about the number of possibilities of the algorithm, indeed

Comment: Thanks for idea bro.But,first  how to interchange the operator one by one as you say bro? Nested loop? I think tats a bad idea. Second where and how to store the operators bro. In array? As string? If so, than how to change back the string operators back to original state so that it can do the operations?

Comment: you could use `switch case` (or nested `if`'s or cond?expr1:expr2) to apply different operators for different numbers.

Answer (score 3):

**I would like to state that this is not my original idea. I will add the reference below.Please find the  C++ code below. It might be of some help to you as it has been to me.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void cntdwn(double sum, double previous, string digits, double target, std::string expr) {
   if (digits.length() == 0) {
     if (sum + previous == target) {
       std::cout<<expr << " = " << target;
     }
   } else {
     for (int i = 1; i <= digits.length(); i++) {
       double current = std::stod(digits.substr(0, i));
       string remaining = digits.substr(i);
       cntdwn(sum + previous, current, remaining, target, expr + " + " + std::to_string(current));
       cntdwn(sum, previous * current, remaining, target, expr + " * " + std::to_string(current));
       cntdwn(sum, previous / current, remaining, target, expr + " / " + std::to_string(current));
       cntdwn(sum + previous, -current, remaining, target, expr + " - " + std::to_string(current));
     }
   }
 }

 void f(string digits, double target) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= digits.length(); i++) {
     string current = digits.substr(0, i);
     cntdwn(0, std::stod(current), digits.substr(i), target, current);
   }
 }

int main() {
    // The digits go as concatenated string
    f("5373",11);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
5 * 3.000000 - 7.000000 + 3.000000 = 11
```

**References**:

[Generate all combinations of mathematical expressions that add to target (Java homework/interview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594710/generate-all-combinations-of-mathematical-expressions-that-add-to-target-java-h)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459857/using-operators-and-4-4-4-4-digits-find-all-formulas-that-would-resolve

https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5735906000502784

**Additional Note**

```
a) This code will not make any combinations for the digits. For example if we give (4,4,4,4) as numbers and 10 as target then it will not give any result as the solution in  that case should be [(44-4)/4] {this example has been picked from second reference].

b) And this problem is a classic algorithmic problme popularly known as "Countdown Problem" picked from famous UK game.
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation Rudrani. Can give me idea on how to include bracket into the equations?

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser#Alternatives_to_Dijkstra.27s_Algorithm . There is an example at the bottom on how to make an equation fully paranthesized.